# Amadeus Web Services - Fair Quote API

Tags: amadeus

I am trying to find the equivalent of FQP/FQD/FQN queries in the Amadeus SOAP service (Flight) API, but couldn't find one. I checked the API documents as well with no luck. There is command cryptic API to call the GDS commands, but the response is raw data as in the terminal, not a structured one. I need structured data response to precess data in the system.

Is there any SOAP APIs available to get the fare details and the rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a question best sent to Amadeus directly! It's hard to know exactly what you are after without more information. Also Amadeus offer a wide variety of doing basically the same thing and your business can be better off using one or the other - its really impossible to tell without background information.

Check out these webservice calls:

> **Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass**
>
> The function Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass is used to price itineraries.
>   It can return one or several fare recommendations for the passenger(s) and for the itinerary of the active PNR. Only booking classes present in the flight segment of the PNR are considered.
>   After calling Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass function, the system keeps the recommendations stored internally for three minutes in a dedicated context. This context can be used to create a TST by using Ticket_CreateTSTFromPricing.
>
> **Fare_PricePNRWithLowerFares**
>
> The function Fare_PricePNRWithLowerFares is used to display the lowest available fare for a given itinerary.
>   "Lowest available" means that this fare is applicable in a booking class where there are still enough seats available for the passengers of the PNR. This class might not be the one currently present in the flight segment of the PNR. In this case, rebooking might be necessary.
>   It can return one or several fare recommendations for the passenger(s) and for the itinerary of the active PNR.
>   After calling Fare_PricePNRWithLowerFares function, the system keeps the recommendations stored internally for three minutes in a dedicated context. This context can be used to create a TST by using Ticket_CreateTSTFromPricing. Please not that in case rebooking is required, it must be done (for example, using Air_RebookAirSegment) before TST creation.
>
> **Fare_InformativeBestPricingWithoutPNR**
>
> The InformativeBestPricingWithoutPNR function provided in the Fare interface is used to price informatively an itinerary without any PNR. If a PNR exists, it is neither taken into account nor updated. No pricing record (TST) is created to store the results.
>
> **Fare_QuoteItinerary**
>
> The QuoteItinary transaction (FQP) quotes fares for passenger types without existing reservations (PNR). Pricing is executed according to the principles of IATA resolutions as well as according to specific user requirements, if industry conform or individual.

Most likely there are more options available (that I don't know about).

Documentation available at https://webservices.amadeus.com/ - login required.